# Using Angular ngx-pipes to Sort a GroupBy

Tags: angular

Using ngx-pipes in Angular 6, is it possible to sort a groupBy? For example, I have a list of tasks. I can group tasks by day and display in ascending order. But how do I display tasks in descending date order?

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let task of tasks | groupBy: 'startDate' | pairs">
    <div>Group name: {{task[0]}}</div>
    <div class="row" *ngFor="let t of task[1]">
        <div>Task: {{t.name}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use the reverse pipe to display tasks in descending order.

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let task of tasks | groupBy: 'startDate' | pairs | reverse">
    <div>Group name: {{task[0]}}</div>
    <div class="row" *ngFor="let t of task[1]">
        <div>Task: {{t.name}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of ngx **pairs** use Angular **keyvalue** pipe then use orderBy

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let task of tasks | groupBy: 'startDate' | keyvalue | orderBy">
    <div>Group name: {{task.key}}</div>
    <div class="row" *ngFor="let t of task.value">
        <div>Task: {{t.name}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps you could explain why you think it's a better idea to use keyvalue and orderBy?